# Insert string output of shell-command in current buffer

Tags: shell-command

The code below calls upon a Python script to generate pinyin from Chinese characters in region:

```elisp
(defun pinyin ()
  "Generate Pinyin from Chinese Characters with Python script, keeping the original Chinese characters intact."
  (interactive)
  (let ((cmdStr
         (format
          "python3 -c \"import pinyin; print(pinyin.get(\'%s\', delimiter=\' \'))\""
          (buffer-substring (region-beginning) (region-end)))))
    (insert
     (format "\n%s"
             (shell-command cmdStr (buffer-file-name))))))
```

I would like the script to insert the pinyin on a new line under the selected Chinese characters.

The above script correctly displays the desired output in the mini-buffer but inserts `0` at the place where the pinyin should be.

What went wrong and how can I get this working properly?

Comment: Use `(shell-command cmdStr t)` to insert the output of the command at point in the current buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(buffer-file-name)` returns the full pathname of the file visited in the current buffer but that is *NOT* the name of the buffer, so the output is saved in a *different buffer*. The name of the current buffer is returned by calling the function `buffer-name`. But the doc string for shell-command says:

> The optional second argument OUTPUT-BUFFER, if non-nil,
>   says to put the output in some other buffer.
>   If OUTPUT-BUFFER is a buffer or buffer name, erase that buffer
>   and insert the output there; a non-nil value of
>   ‘shell-command-dont-erase-buffer’ prevents the buffer from being
>   erased.  If OUTPUT-BUFFER is not a buffer and not nil, insert the
>   output in current buffer after point leaving mark after it.  This
>   cannot be done asynchronously.

and I think it is easier to use a non-nil value that is not a buffer for the OUTPUT-BUFFER argument: that way, we "insert the
output in current buffer after point leaving mark after it" - and the easiest non-nil value to type is `t`, so use

```
(shell-command cmdStr t)
```

in your function.

EDIT: Do *NOT* do

```el
...
(insert (format "\n%s" (shell-command cmdStr t)))
```

That will format the *return value* of `(shell-command ...)`, which seems to be `nil` in my experiments, as a string and insert it in the buffer, before the output of the command.

You should just do:

```el
...
(let ((cmdStr ...))
  (shell-command cmdStr t))
...
```

Not sure why you are getting the value of `(region-end)` however.

Comment: Why is the value of `(region-end)` inserted before my desired output?

Comment: Because you are inserting the formatted return value of the call to `shell-command`. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: When I simplify to `(insert (shell-command cmdStr t))`, `t` got inserted before the desired value instead. How can the unnecessary insertion be avoided?

Comment: Do *NOT* use insert! See my edit.